# nginx simple uri wildcard

Tags: redirect, path, nginx

I'm trying to do something that I thought it was going to be very simple, but turned out is giving me lot of troubles.

I have a vhost under nginx defined like this

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name test.com;
    root   /var/apps/failover/;
    location / {
                index  index.html index.htm;
            }
}
```

What I want to do is that all the request that have a request_uri set (ex: test.com/something) will go to only test.com/.

I want a kind of wildcard for uri that will redirect the user to the root of the vhost.

I tried many combination of rewrite statements, but I didn't have anything working.

I'm sure it's supposed to be simple, but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work with something like this:

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name text.com;
    root   /var/apps/failover/;
    location / {
      index index.html;
      error_page 404 =200 /index.html;
    }
 }
```

Unsure if it's the best way, but works fine and it does what I need

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understand you right you want to all requests coming to your site be served by some kind of `index` file, yes? I suppose it's truth, because if any request will be rewrited to only domain name without any additional paths then I don't know what else can you think about.

So, with such assumption, there is one more question: *do you want to redirect user with `301` http status code as permanent redirect (user will know)* **or just** *softly redirect inside your app without any back information (user won't know)*

If first one then this rewrite directive should work, paste it before any `location` block:

```
rewrite /.+ / permanent ;
```

If second one then this `rewrite` directive should work, paste it before any `location` block:

```
rewrite ^/.* / last;
```

Also you need a `location` block which will serve path `/`

```
location / {
   try_files index.html =404;
}
```

With this `location` and `try_files` directive we say that whatever comes to your app it doesn't matter because it always has to use our `index.html` file or return with http status code `404` (not found error).

Will it help you or are you looking for something different?

Comment: I tried both options: for the first case I get redirection loop, for the second case I get rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/" (500 response and I can see that in nginx log)

Comment: server {
        listen 80;
        server_name test.com;
        root   /var/apps/failover/;
        rewrite /.+ / permanent;
        location / {
                    index  index.html index.htm;
                }
}

Comment: but did you use directive `try_files index.html =404`?